# how to create android service (equalizer) to seek to bar code that I have?

Tags: android, service, android-seekbar

I need to transform the code below, which is an equalizer, and a service for android that when I close it the effect of it remains, is how to do this?

The reason for this is so that when I go back to the equalizer and execution screen, he did not miss the ifeitos that I set ...

I need some tips on how to do this, I could not even declare findview by id in the services: /

thank you

public class equalizer2 extends Activity {

```
private ArrayList<SeekBar> eqSbs;
private Spinner eqPresetSpn;
private Spinner prSpn;
private Equalizer eq;
private PresetReverb pr;
private Visualizer vs;
private SharedPreferences pref;
public AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity mp3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.equalizer2);

    eqSbs = new ArrayList<SeekBar>();
    eqPresetSpn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.eqPresetSpn2);
    prSpn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.reverbSpn2);

      setEqualizer();
      setReverb();
    //  setVisualizer();        
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_save1 :
        return save(1);
    case R.id.menu_save2 :
        return save(2);
    case R.id.menu_save3 :
        return save(3);
    case R.id.menu_load1 :
        return load(1);
    case R.id.menu_load2 :
        return load(2);
    case R.id.menu_load3 :
        return load(3);
    }
    return false;
}

private void setEqualizer() {       
    eq = new Equalizer(0, mp3.mp2.getAudioSessionId());
    eq.setEnabled(true);
    final short minEQLevel = eq.getBandLevelRange()[0];
    final short maxEQLevel = eq.getBandLevelRange()[1];

    TableLayout eqLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.eq2);
    short bands = eq.getNumberOfBands();
    for (short i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
        final short band = i;
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TextView freq = new TextView(this);
        freq.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        freq.setText((eq.getCenterFreq(band) / 1000) + "Hz");
        row.addView(freq);

        eqSbs.add(new SeekBar(this));
        eqSbs.get(i).setMax(maxEQLevel - minEQLevel);
        eqSbs.get(i).setProgress(eq.getBandLevel(band) - minEQLevel);
        eqSbs.get(i).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                eq.setBandLevel(band, (short) (progress + minEQLevel));
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        });
        row.addView(eqSbs.get(i));

        eqLayout.addView(row);
    }

    ArrayList<String> presetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (short i = 0; i < eq.getNumberOfPresets(); i++) {
        presetList.add(eq.getPresetName(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, presetList);
    eqPresetSpn.setAdapter(adapter);
    eqPresetSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            eq.usePreset((short)position);
            for (int i = 0; i < eq.getNumberOfBands(); i++) {
                eqSbs.get(i).setProgress(eq.getBandLevel((short)i) - minEQLevel);
            }
            Log.d("EQ", eq.getProperties().toString());
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
    });
}

private void setReverb() {
    pr = new PresetReverb(0, mp3.mp2.getAudioSessionId());
    pr.setEnabled(true);
    prSpn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_NONE);
                break;
            case 1:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM);
                break;
            case 2:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMROOM);
                break;
            case 3:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
                break;
            case 4:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMHALL);
                break;
            case 5:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
                break;
            case 6:
                pr.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_PLATE);
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
    });
}

private boolean save(int i) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("eq" + i, eq.getProperties().toString());
    editor.putString("pr" + i, pr.getProperties().toString());
    return editor.commit();
}

private boolean load(int i) {
    eq.setProperties(new Equalizer.Settings(pref.getString("eq" + i, "Equalizer;curPreset=0;numBands=5;band1Level=300;band2Level=0;band3Level=0;band4Level=0;band5Level=300")));
    short bands = eq.getNumberOfBands();
    short minEQLevel = eq.getBandLevelRange()[0];
    // eqPresetSpn.setSelection(eq.getCurrentPreset());
    for (int j = 0; j < bands; j++) {
         eqSbs.get(j).setProgress(eq.getBandLevel((short)j) - minEQLevel);
    }
    pr.setProperties(new PresetReverb.Settings(pref.getString("pr" + i, "PresetReverb;preset=0")));
    switch (pr.getPreset()) {
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_NONE :
        prSpn.setSelection(0);
        break;
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM :
        prSpn.setSelection(1);
        break;
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMROOM :
        prSpn.setSelection(2);
        break;
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM :
        prSpn.setSelection(3);
        break;
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMHALL :
        prSpn.setSelection(4);
        break;
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL :
        prSpn.setSelection(5);
        break;
    case PresetReverb.PRESET_PLATE :
        prSpn.setSelection(6);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}